# Use Illustrator 3D rotation in After Effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, 3d, adobe-after-effects

In illustrator I have a logo that I want to animate in 3D. Now, the logo has already 3D shapes made with the Extrude tool inside Illustrator. Inside that tool you can rotate your shape in 3D space. I rotated with the following coordinates:

X: -45°
Y: 35°
Z: -30°

Now to animate it in After Effects, I imported the flat shape and tried to rotate it in the same way with the same coordinates. The result comes out completely different (The black B should match the white one):

[image]

How is this possible and how do I fix it?

Comment: The rotation axis work differently in AI's extrude vs AE (i.e. global space vs object axis).. not entirely sure how to work out the correct rotation though. Do you really need the rotation? if not just expand the shape in AI

Comment: @Cai hi, thanks for replying! I need the rotation because I want to animate the 3D shape in AE, and not just keep it stationary.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't true 3D shapes in Illustrator. It only outputs 2D. To rotate a 3D object in AE it must be rendered in a 3d drafting program. Sketch up is free and easy to learn but I am not sure if it exports anything that will retain 3D in AE.